# Как одно соотношение сторон довести до нужного?

Tags: любой-язык

Допустим, пользователь рисует прямоугольник и я хочу, что бы он рисовался только с определенным соотношением сторон.

Как я могу текущий прямоугольник оптимально подогнать под необходимое соотношение?

Текущее соотношение я вычисляю, как:

Ширина/НОД : Высота/НОД

А вот, как мне зная, что текущее соотношение меня неудоволитворяет подпилить текущий прямоуголник до нужного?

Т.е добавить необходимое кол-во пикселей.

На ум приходит перебор c добавлением +1, пока не получу нужный размер, но скорее всего должна быть какая-то формула...

Получилось что-то такое по ответу splash58:

```
Rectangle CorrectScale(Rectangle rect, int newWRatio, int newHRatio)
{
    int h = rect.Height;
    int w = rect.Width;
    float ratio = newWRatio / (float)newHRatio;
    if (rect.Height < rect.Width) h = (int)(rect.Height * ratio);
    else if (rect.Height > rect.Width) w = (int)(rect.Width / ratio);
    return new Rectangle(rect.X, rect.Y, w, h);
}
```

Но немного не то...

Answer (score 2):

Если высота меньше ширины, берете высоту, умножаете на ratio.

Если меньше ширины - готово.

Если больше, ширину делите на ratio. Готово

Comment: Дополнил вопрос. Типа что-то типа такого должно быть, да?

Comment: Похоже, только ветку надо предусмотреть для поворота на 90 градусов, если высота больше ширины

Comment: Что-то не скейлится=(

Comment: раз любой язык, через час буду не на телефоне напишу

Comment: Т.е например, выделил юзер 8/13, а мне нужно, что бы это соответствовало масштабу 2/3, значит нужно подогнать его например к 8/12.

Comment: вам именно в целых надо

Answer (score 0):

Я вот так вот сделать решил:

```
   Rectangle CorrectScale(Rectangle rect, int ratioW, int ratioH,int gcd)
    {
        int w = rect.Width;
        int h = rect.Height;
        float ratio = ratioW / (float)ratioH;
        if (w / gcd % ratioW!=0)
        {
            w = (w / ratioW) * ratioW;
        }
        h = (int)(w / ratio);
        return new Rectangle(rect.X, rect.Y, w, h);
    }
```

Если ширина деленная на наибольшее общее кратное не кратна желаемому новому отношению, то делаю ее кратной, а потом на основании этого высчитываю новый H. Получается что-то похожее на то, что нужно с погрешностями.